# Unable to connect to EC2 Linux instance from Windows 10 CMD using ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, acl, ec2-ami

I have a running `EC2` instance that is running `Linux OS`(`Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03`) on it.

Given that `Windows 10` has `SSH` client available in the command prompt, I was trying to `SSH` into my `EC2` instance using the `SSH` private key(`.pem` file) provided by `AWS` as a key pair during the setup of the `EC2` instance.

The command I am using on `cmd` is :

```
ssh -i private_key.pem ec2-user@3.133.96.240
```

Here `private_key.pem` is the name of the private key file provided by `AWS`.

But I keep getting the error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'private_key.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "private_key.pem": bad permissions
ec2-user@3.133.96.240: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Some things I would like to clarify:

1. There are similar questions on StackOverflow. Those questions actually involve trying to connect to the `EC2` instance from a host that is running `MacOS`/`Linux`(any `UNIX` based OS). In my case I am trying to connect from `Windows` 10 host using command prompt.
2. In answer to such other questions as discussed in (1), people have suggested trying to change the file permission of the private key file(`.pem`) file to read-only(`chmod 444 file.pem`). In response, I tried making my `.pem` file as read-only from the file properties in my `Windows`. This did not help. I keep getting the same error.
3. I am able to connect to other remote Linux hosts from my Windows 10 cmd, which suggests there is probably no problem with my Windows 10 SSH client.
4. I know this connection can be made easier by using `Putty` instead of `CMD`, but that is not what this question is about. Just assume because of some constraints I cant use `Putty`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I made a [detail tutorial for connecting to aws instance from windows using ssh here](https://www.beehexa.com/devdocs/aws/how-to-connect-to-aws-ec2-linux-instance-using-ssh/) if it may help

Answer (score 5):

In **Windows 10**, locate the *.pem* file in question and right-click on it.

From **Properties-->Security--> Advanced**:

1. Make sure your user is the owner of the file
2. Give **Read&Execute** permissions for your user specifically,
    while removing all other permissions on the file for other users or groups.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For windows users using powershell or bash:

`cd` into your_keys.pem folder.

type

`icacls.exe aws_keys.pem /reset`

`icacls.exe aws_keys.pem /grant:r "$($env:username):(r)"`

`icacls.exe aws_keys.pem /inheritance:r`

Note: These commands give same permissions like `chmod 400 your_keys.pem` on mac...

and then use `ssh -i "your_keys.pem" ubuntu@your_public_server_ip.com`

Answer (score 0):

You are right - it's because Windows permissions model differs from Linux.

See more: [Understanding Linux File Permissions - Linux.com](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/)

There are many tips howto fix the issue. I'd suggest to apply [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/blob/latestw_all/contrib/win32/openssh/OpenSSHCommonUtils.psm1) script from this repository: [openssh-portable](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable)

As per [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/pull/110/files?file-filters%5B%5D=.c&file-filters%5B%5D=.h&file-filters%5B%5D=.psm1&file-filters%5B%5D=.pub&file-filters%5B%5D=.vcxproj&file-filters%5B%5D=No+extension#diff-52d2aa6d93f03d8fd2aee92417038d24)

> .Synopsis Sets the Secure File ACL. 
>   1. Removed all user acl except Administrators group, system, and current user
>   2. whether or not take the owner .Outputs N/A .Inputs FilePath - The path to the file takeowner - if want to take the ownership

Comment: Acttually I do understand Linux file permissions. But sorry I did not get the part about the script from openssh-portable

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/blob/670d06230258b38129049dd8f8208b6e3737fc62/contrib/win32/openssh/OpenSSHCommonUtils.psm1) commit

Comment: Still dont get it. am new to this stuff and all n your answer seem overwhelming. nvm I'l figure some other way(maybe use putty or something)

Answer (score 0):

In windows, there is a different method to give permissions to keys.pem file.
Write the following lines in your terminal:

```
$ icacls.exe your_key_name.pem /reset
$ icacls.exe your_key_name.pem /grant:r "$($env:username):(r)"
$ icacls.exe your_key_name.pem /inheritance:r
```

Your keys.pem will now have the same restrictions as "chmod 400" in Linux.

Source: [[Solved] WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!](https://www.techaeblogs.live/2023/02/unprotected-private-key-file.html)